# Apache Library importing on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apache-commons, android-library

I need to import `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringuUtils` in my android project. But when I import the rar file then I lost my 'res' folder including all sub-folders and files from my project and when I open my main xml file then it shows me 'no SDK found'. But I have noticed that when my **gradle** sync is complete after importing the rar file then in the right-above side of screen it shows me a popup `Android framework detected`.
So now anyone can help me please. ..

Answer (score 3):

I think you should let Gradle to manage the dependencies. add `compile org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0` to your android 'dependencies' section.

Comment: Ok if I add this to the gradle section then won't I have to import the external library?

Comment: I mean if I add it to the gradle and I only import 'org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils' then won't I have to add the rar file of apache separtely?

Comment: Thank you. But if I add rar file in the app:libs folder then why I don't find my res folder?  What do you think about this?

Comment: eh.. did you mean 'rar' is 'jar', 'res' is 'src'?

Comment: Yes. I mean 'jar' but not the 'src'. That is 'res' where include strings, values, mipmap etc...

Comment: why a jar library need be found in resource folder?

Comment: No no no brother. Sorry for wasting your valuable time. But you are not understanding. I said when I import 'org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils' in the libs folder and sync the gradle then I lost my whole 'res' folder. And I get a message saying 'no sdk found'.

Comment: well, using Gradle, every project structure things is under the control of build.gralde. maybe paste your gradle script file. and keep editing gradle script rather than other ways like 'import' you did.

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: Sorry for the pasting style

Comment: maybe paste them in question body.

Comment: Sorry man having problem  with submitting  the code... Ok brother  thanks for your time. I'll try it later